# item operations multiple is_granted not working - api platform

Tags: symfony4, api-platform.com

I am trying to secure my post operation on entity by allowing it to 3 roles. ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER and ROLE_LEADER. Every user have only one role.

When I was testing if it works by removing ROLE_LEADER from the code below, I found out, that a user with ROLE_LEADER can still create user.

I have tried to make some error if the changes are taking place, they are.

I have the following operation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ApiResource(
 *    itemOperations={
 *         "post"={"access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') or is_granted('ROLE_USER')", "access_control_message"="You are not owner of this user."},
 *         "delete"={"access_control"="
                is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')
                or (is_granted('ROLE_USER') and (previous_object.getOwner() == user or previous_object.getOwner().getOwner() == user))
                or (is_granted('ROLE_LEADER') and previous_object.getOwner() == user)
            ", "access_control_message"="You are not owner of this user."},
 *     },
 * )
 */
```

Delete operation works as expected, however I cannot understand why I can still create a user when I am posting data from user that has ROLE_LEADER.

Thank you for your time

Comment: can you post your security.yaml?
and keep in mind that the role system is hierarchical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was that I have needed to move

```
"post"={"access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') or is_granted('ROLE_USER')", "access_control_message"="You are not owner of this user."},
```

from itemOperations to collectionOperations

Answer (score 0):

Every user that logs in, always has at least the role `ROLE_USER`. See the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#roles) for more information.

Therefore `is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') or is_granted('ROLE_USER')` means any logged in user is granted access (because of `or is_granted('ROLE_USER')` ), which is also why your user with `ROLE_LEADER` can still post data (because this user will *also* have the role `ROLE_USER`).

A solution is to create another user role and use that one instead.

Comment: Thanks, but I have removed the $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER'; from the entity, because i did not wanted to have that role by default. This is why I am surprised that it still counts it as default role. 

I have refactored access_control from ROLE_USER to ROLE_MANAGER, and my test user with ROLE_LEADER can post (create) user when access control is set to "access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') or is_granted('ROLE_MANAGER')"

Comment: ROLE_LEADER can also post when the post item operation is "access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')"

Comment: I think i just figured out, POST is collection operation, it´s not listed in item, i did debug the debug:router command and it stated "api_users_post_collection" so i have tried to move the post part from itemOperations to collectionOperations and it works. makes no sense to me why posting single item is a collection operation.